# Magento Sales Guest form

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, forms

I'm trying to find out where the /sales/guest/form/ submits to.

Is it an email address that this goes to or does it search for a particular order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It searches for a guest order that matches the input data and then shows it.

The page is `sales/guest/view` and works in the same way as `sales/order/view` in the customer account

Comment: So it's a simple search and view? Thanks!

Comment: yes, it can be used to give guest customers a way to track their order